# merge specific revisions only with svn from command line

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-merge

How can I merge in a list of changes I have committed to the trunk to my branch?

The list of revision are all of *my* changes and these are the only revisions I wish to merge to the branch (.)

I have tried this, but to no avail.

> svn merge
>   -r498,509,514,516,518,520,523,527,529,539,543,563,565,568,590,591,597 https://svn.ayrshireminis.com/svn/MINI/trunk/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `-c` instead of `-r`